# Extension of Holder's Inequality

Tags: lebesgue-measure

I found the proof of [Generalization of Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_H.C3.B6lder.27s_inequality) from Wikipedia

I get the other part, but I don't get why in case 1: we have the inequality 
$\Vert f_1f_2\cdots f_n \Vert_r \leq \Vert f_1f_2 \cdots f_{n-1} \Vert_r \Vert f_n \Vert_\infty $

Could someone explain this?

Comment: You have copied the inequality incorrectly. The product on the right hand side should end with $f_{n-1}$.

Comment: oh yeah you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

Take $f = f_1 f_2 \ldots f_{n-1}$ and $g = f_n$. Then, by Hölder's inequality we have
$$\|fg\|_r \leq \|f\|_r \|g\|_\infty,$$
i.e.
$$\|f_1 f_2 \ldots f_{n-1} f_n\|_r \leq \|f_1 f_2 \ldots f_{n-1}\|_r \|f_n\|.$$